# When is the work of a C# Parallel.ForEach done?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, asp.net-mvc-4, parallel-processing

I'm developing an MVC4 website in C#. The following code should fill a `ConcurrentBag` (DisplayModels) with items before passing everything to the view.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(model.Products, p =>
    {
        model.DisplayModels.Add(new DisplayBoardModel()
        {
            Market = model.Market,
            Product = p
        });
    });

    return View(model);
```

I'm finding that on any given execution DisplayModels appears to be filled to a different point. As if the ForEach is completing before each background task has returned.

My understanding of the `Parallel.ForEach` was that it processed each item in parallel but still blocked the calling thread until all of it's work was done. Is this not correct?

Is there something else I should be doing to stop the action returning before the model is ready? Using a normal `foreach` worked fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Parallel.ForEach()` works fine, and completes all at once as expected.

But your `model.DisplayModels.Add()` probably isn't thread-safe. What collection are you using?

You could fix this by a) using a Concurrent collection for DisplayModels or b) turn the ForEach into a PLINQ query. But unless `DisplayBoardModel()` does some heavy CPU work (and a ctor usually doesn't) there is little point in making this parallel.

So, just use a simple `foreach()`

---

#### Edit, new information

> each DisplayBoardModel make a database request

So this is a potential cause. Does every Db operation create its own Connection (Context)? Any chance that an exception is silently ignored?

Comment: The OP says it's a `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: Thanks @Henk. The collection is a `ConcurrentBag` so the `.Add()` method should be safe. The reason for going parallel is that each `DisplayBoardModel` make a database request which could potentially be a little slow

Comment: OK, was that `ConcurrentBag` there in the first Post? I missed that. (Editing).

Comment: It was mentioned but I missed the DB stuff out, sorry.
Each model has it's own EF context that it uses for DB connectivity. I can't see any obvious place where an exception could be dropped silently, I'll investigate further...

Comment: That said, it works perfectly every time if I use a normal `foreach` so surely the only kind of exception could be something like `OutOfMemory`, too many DB connections or something to do with the thread pool?

Comment: Could be a lot of things... As a diagnostic, try throwing an exception from the core of that Db code, see where it ends up...

Comment: I've changed tack on this and am no longer using the `Parallel.ForEach`. As such I've done no further testing on this. It seems quite likely that a DB error was causing this problem though so I'm marking this as the correct answer.